# cmake include file and then file path

Tags: path, cmake, include

- source file and CMakeLists.txt. (path : ~/work/src)
- source for unittest. and CMakeLists.txt (path : ~/work/src/unittest/)

In ~/work/src/unittest/CMakeLists.txt, I use include command

```
include (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CMakeLists.txt)
```

In ~/work/src/CMakeLists.txt ,

```
file (STRINGS "../profile" profile)
```

i want to use cmake in the unittest path.

error msg :
`CMake Error at ~/work/src/CMakeLists.txt:13 (file):
  file STRINGS file
  "~/work/src/unittest/../profile" cannot be
  read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)`

How can i do?

Answer (score 1):

When `include()` CMake-script, you don't change current source directory (and binary one). But usually `CMakeLists.txt` expects source directory to reflect  location of `CMakeLists.txt` itself.

Instead of `include()`ing `CMakeLists.txt`, use `add_subdirectory`:

```
add_subdirectory(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../" # Source directory, contains CMakeLists.txt file
    "myproject" # Build directory, will be created and used for output files
)
```